# What is a full-page navigation page called?

Tags: website-design

First of all, new to this side of stackexchange, this may not be the correct area to ask this question - and if that is so I would like to apologize in advance.

So, I was searching around for templates for a specific project I'm working on to get some ideas.

I had made a page awhile back which is basically a page that has big buttons on it only, sort of like a full-page navigation menu. (Image below)

I was wondering if there was a name for this type of page - because I am unable to find anymore like it.

Its sort of like a landing page, that just has several buttons that lead to different parts of the website.

Image of the site I made:
[image]

Comment: Personally I'd call it a navigation page. What sort of thing are you looking for from the answer? Design inspiration? I'd consider looking at portal design based on what you say here.

Comment: My own response to my own question was locked due to it not answering the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not a very specific name, but it looks like a variation of **"Clean Entry Points"** navigation model. According to the book "**[Designing Interfaces](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1449379702)**":

> These entry points act as "doors" into the main content of the site or
>   application. From these starting points, guide the user gently and
>   unambiguously into the application until he has enough context to
>   continue by himself.
>
> Collectively, these entry points should cover most reasons why anyone
>   would be there. There might be only one or two entry points, or many;
>   it depends on what fits your design.